# Посчитать бит-маску для ProcessorAffinity

Tags: c#

Есть примерно такой метод

```cs
Process mproc = new Process();
mproc.StartInfo.FileName = "";
mproc.Start();
mproc.ProcessorAffinity = А как?;
```

Так вот,нужно посчитать битмаску для `ProcessorAffinity` на основе количества потоков

Что-то типа такого: всего 12 потоков,нужно ограничить до 6. Нужен метод,который сможет конвертировать 6 в то, что примет `ProcessorAffinity`

Comment: Вы никак не сможете ограничить количество потоков таким образом. Affinity задает список доступных процессу ядер процессора. На работу с потоками это никак не влияет.

Comment: А так `(nint)(Math.Pow(2, 6) - 1)`, это будет означать с 1 по 6 ядро

Comment: а,понял,спасибо,я просто изначально неправильно объяснил,упс

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С 1 по 6 ядро будет выглядеть как-то так

```
mproc.ProcessorAffinity = (nint)((1 << 6) - 1);
```

логика

```
1
0000001
<< 6
1000000
- 1
0111111
```

`nint` и `IntPtr` - одно и то же.

[Process.ProcessorAffinity](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.processoraffinity)